# Heroku Connect vs Cache

Tags: heroku, heroku-connect

I want to make some of the data in Salesforce available for my users on the homepage. I could just use Heroku Connect and synchronize the objects or I just build a caching service and load the required objects into the cache and access it from there.

How's your experience with Heroku Connect? Is it really as simple as it looks on the paper?

Comment: Is this salesforce data that you want to make available on the salesforce homepage?

Comment: We don't use a Salesforce Homepage. The homepage is not built on saleaforce.

Comment: If you build this caching service, how will the app refresh the cache? Is it already getting authorization tokens from user oauth logins? Or would you have something like outbound messages sent when there are changes in salesforce?

Comment: The cache is getting updated through the API. The data is accessible by the general public. No authorization is needed.

Comment: To be honest, I think you'd be fine either way. I'd be curious to see if anyone else here can see a benefit that one has over the other.

Comment: are you already paying for heroku connect?  In my experience it's not very cost effective.  It doesn't sound like you really need it for your purposes (really built for 2-way synchronizations). I'd just pull data from the Rest API

Comment: I think you are right @NSjonas - The price is the deciding factor. I didn't know it's that expensive. Thank you very much!

Comment: @NSjonas Please post that as an answer.